# Why string concated with arrow function statement returns string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have a following code

```js
const foo = "foo" + (x => x + 2);
console.log(foo);
```

When executed, it logs `'foox => x + 2'`

So I wonder why when concatinating a string with an arrow function statement (without `()` at the end), we get a string back and there is no syntax error (`=>` should give a syntax error in that context).

---

More question:

So why does it behave that way?

When I do `"a" + console.log`, I get `afunction () { [native code] }` so why it doesn't return `foo[Function]` in the same way as `console.log(x => x + 2)` does?

```js
console.log(console.log) // [Function: bound consoleCall]
console.log(x => x + 2) // [Function]
console.log("" + (x => x + 2)) // foox => x + 2 -- why not foo[Function]?
```

---

Or is it just another [Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) of JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no syntax error because there simply isn't.  The value of a function reference when coerced to a string is the text of the function.

Comment: you need assign the expression to some object and operator like const foo = "foo" + OBJECT.operator(x => x + 2);....example= foo = "foo" + myList.find(x => x + 2);

Comment: To be clear, `console.log(x => x + 2)` doesn't **return** `[Function]`.  It **returns** `undefined`.  It **displays** `[Function]`.  The browser's developer tools behaviour is even more sophisticated than just displaying text the way node.js does, it offers a whole user interface for inspecting the function.

Answer (score 1):

`(x => x + 2)` gets compiled as a function which is itself an object.

`'foo' + (x => x + 2)` is an addition between a string and an object. Since the second hand is an object, javascript will call toString() to convert the object to its string and concatenate with 'foo', and that returns `'x => x + 2'`

Comment: Why does `toString()` behave in that way? When I do `"a" + console.log`, I get `afunction () { [native code] }`so why it doesn't return `foo[Function]` in the same way as `console.log(x => x + 2)` does?

Comment: The term `[Function]` that you're seeing is not a `String` - it's the way your terminal has chosen to represent a Function to you.

Comment: @Gershom so why `console.log.toString()` gets `function () { [native code] }`? I'm so confused right now lol

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is very multifaceted; it will use one of a number of techniques to display a value in a helpful way. In fact, `console.log`'s format for displaying values is not even standardized. Different JavaScript environments may show different `console.log` representations for the same value. Look at the chrome `console.log` for example; it doesn't even print text, but rather interactive UI-like elements which can be expanded with drop-down arrows!

These differences in display between JavaScript environments will vary more for complex data-types (because there is more subjectivity regarding how best to display them). Most consoles, however, will render `String` values in roughly the same way (because there is very little subjectivity in how best to display a `String`; simply print its characters!)

So keep in mind that `console.log(value)` is simply "some attempt to show you `value` in a useful way", it can vary across environments (it is non-standardized), and it will vary less for simple data types.

Finally, notice that JavaScript's most fundamental type `Object` has a `toString` method, which can translate most values to a `String`. This *is* standardized. If I have a function `let myCoolFunction = () => { /* ... */ };`, and I call `myCoolFunction.toString()`, there is only a single way that resulting `String` can look (if it looks any different, your JavaScript environment is invalid).

Now we can see the difference between 1:

```
console.log(value);
```

And 2:

```
console.log(value.toString());
```

1 allows for the subjective `console.log` to display `value` however it likes. 2 asks `console.log` to display a standardized string, the result of converting `value` to a `String`. In this second case `console.log` is still subjective, but it is printing a string, and there's pretty much only one way to do that; the result will be consistent across environments.

In your examples, concatenating `"" + something` implicitly causes `toString` to be called on `something`.